# Google Drive API Java Permissions 500 Internal Error

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have the next method to share Google Drive files:

```
public static boolean shareFile(HttpServletRequest httpReq, String fileId, String user, String rol, boolean commenter) {        
    Drive service = getService(httpReq) ;

    if (service != null){   
        Permission newPermission = new Permission();

        newPermission.setValue(user);
        newPermission.setType("user");
        newPermission.setRole(rol);

        if (commenter)
            newPermission.setAdditionalRoles(Arrays.asList("commenter"));

        try {      
            service.permissions().insert(fileId,  newPermission).execute();
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {      
            System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);   
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Everything works fine when variable commenter is false (we don't set addiotional roles), but if I want a user to have role "reader" and "commenter" I get the next error:

```
    An error occured: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
    {
        "code" : 500,
        "errors" : [ {
            "domain" : "global",
            "message" : "Internal Error",
            "reason" : "internalError"
        }   ],
        "message" : "Internal Error"
    }
```

Did anyone experience with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

I got this kind of error if passed **id** field is not correct.
Strange error code, i think something like 4XX is more suitable here (not 500).

100% reproducible.

Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B28tlN6SgYRaNVRFRENpRFN3bGs/permissions?key={YOUR_API_KEY}


{
 "role": "reader",
 "type": "user",
 "id": "16887416236869940585"
}
```

Response:

```
500 Internal Server Error

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

Hope Google Drive API error messaging will be more informative that (500 Internal Server Error).